# In Feynman lecture vol1，chapter12 friction between two wet glasses, is there any atmospheric pressure related during the process?

Tags: pressure, friction, atmospheric-science

In Feynman lecture vol1，chapter12 friction between two wet glasses, is there any atmospheric pressure related during the process? Does the water between two glasses make use of atmosphere pressure? Or the the atmosphere has been included in N.
“If we now wet
the glass plate and the bottom of the tumbler and pull again, we find that it
binds, and if we look closely we shall find scratches, because the water is able
to lift the grease and the other contaminants off the surface, and then we really have a glass-to-glass contact; this contact is so good that it holds tight and resists separation so much that the glass is torn apart; that is, it makes scratches”

Comment: Yes, pressure pushes on the glass slides. You should focus on the difference between the two cases, no water / film of water. And that in particular what is written should hold for sliding. For separating the two glasses by lift, water tension should be at work, too.